# How to set vite (preview) production port?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, svelte, vite

I have been looking arround on how to set a production port for vite but I can't find way
I have tried  this vite js config

```js
  server: {
    host: true,
  },
  preview:{
    port:5005
  }
```

but it seems like it can't work

Comment: You use ```server.host``` instead of ```server.port```. I know this is old, but noone mentioned this before.. Maybe it helps somebody with the same trouble :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/#preview-port) this should work

```js
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3030
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8080
  }
})
```

But if it doesn't work add `--port` on preview command in `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vite preview --port 6000"
  },
```

Answer (score 10):

In package.json, add this code

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vite --port 8000"
},
```

In terminal, run the command

```
npm run serve
```

Answer (score 2):

just update you **npm run dev** command to:

```
"dev": "vite --port=8080"
```

in the **package.json** file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).